# Rails - problem with DelayedJobs - wrong number of arguments error. Works fine without DelayedJobs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I'm executing the account creation process as a background task.
The function works well without the "delay". It fails many times when I'm using delayed_jobs. For example, if I send 9 accounts for creation, only 6 will be created.

Here is the handler stored in the delayed_jobs table:

```
--- !ruby/object:Delayed::PerformableMethod
object: !ruby/class 'Tool::AccountCreation'
method_name: :create_account
args:
- ''
- test pmf
- test67@pmf.com
- test pmf
- '2907'
- ''
- 'true'
- '64'
- ''
- 40
```

Here is the error in the delayed_jobs table:

```
wrong number of arguments (given 10, expected 6..7)
```

Here is the controller code that is using delayed_jobs:

```
Tool::AccountCreation.delay.create_account(first_name, last_name, email, password, params[:student_group_id], partner_user_id, params[:send_code_by_email], params[:catalogue_offer_id], remote_login_secret_token, accounts_in_creation.id)
```

Here is the model for my "create_account function:

```
def create_account(first_name, last_name, email, password, student_group_id, partner_user_id, send_code_by_email, catalogue_offer_id, remote_login_secret_token, accounts_in_creation_id, options = {})
    [...]
end
```

Any clues are welcome !

Comment: have you restarted delayed_jobs? it's possible that when delayed_jobs loaded previously it loaded the create_account method that required only 6/7 methods and now it's out of date. Restarting will reload the latest code.

Comment: I've restarted the worker on heroku. I have only 1 worker for background tasks, sometimes the jobs are perfomed on 1st attempt, sometimes it takes a couple of attempts, sometimes it does not work at all.

Comment: all the jobs have the same number of arguments? you're still getting the same 'wrong number of args error'? are you sure your model is actually deployed to heroku? if you run a `heroku console` you can create a new account with 10 args?

Comment: same number of arguments for each job and still the same error. Everything is working when I do not use the ".delay"

Comment: seems odd. that error indicates a mismatch between the job and the code. it is actually calling the method you expect? if you scale the workers to 0 and scale it back up to 1 it should load the latest code on there?